# Airflow - KubernetesPodOperator - TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-pod

I have already uploaded an image with everything I need to run in GCP using KubernetesPodOperator and I get the message below, could anyone help me understand what is going on?

Below is a summary of my script and error message:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.mssql_to_gcs import MsSqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
import pyarrow
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'catchup': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG('test_kube', default_args=default_args, description='Kubernetes Operator',
         schedule_interval='00 12 01 * *') as dag:
    k = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='kubenm',
                              image="teste-kube:latest",
                              name="test",
                              task_id="test",
                              is_delete_operator_pod=False,
                              hostnetwork=False,
                              dag=dag
                              )

    k
```

This is the first time I am using this operator and I am wondering if it will meet my needs.

Log:

```
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test Traceback (most recent call last):
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     args.func(args)
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     return f(*args, **kwargs)
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 522, in run
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     _run(args, dag, ti)
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 440, in _run
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     pool=args.pool,
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     return func(*args, **kwargs)
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 926, in _run_raw_task
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 111, in execute
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     config_file=self.config_file)
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/kube_client.py", line 56, in get_kube_client
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     return _load_kube_config(in_cluster, cluster_context, config_file)
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/kube_client.py", line 38, in _load_kube_config
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     config.load_kube_config(config_file=config_file, context=cluster_context)
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 645, in load_kube_config
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     persist_config=persist_config)
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 613, in _get_kube_config_loader_for_yaml_file
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     **kwargs)
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 153, in __init__
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     self.set_active_context(active_context)
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 173, in set_active_context
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     context_name = self._config['current-context']
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 495, in __getitem__
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     v = self.safe_get(key)
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 491, in safe_get
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test     key in self.value):
INFO - Job 11344: Subtask test TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
INFO - [[34m2019-09-30 17:18:16,274[0m] {[34mlocal_task_job.py:[0m172} WARNING[0m - State of this instance has been externally set to [1mup_for_retry[0m. Taking the poison pill.[0m
INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 9
INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=9, status='terminated') (9) terminated with exit code -15
INFO - [[34m2019-09-30 17:18:16,303[0m] {[34mlocal_task_job.py:[0m105} INFO[0m
```

Comment: Based solely upon that snippet, it looks like the `KUBECONFIG` is either empty or missing; based on [the fine manual](http://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator) I would guess you need `in_cluster=True` or to otherwise specify `config_file="/wherever/your/kubeconfig/lives"`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Thanks, that solved the previous message but another problem arose: ERROR - Pod Launching failed: Pod took too long to start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 152, in execute
    get_logs=self.get_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py", line 93, in run_pod
    raise AirflowException("Pod took too long to start")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Pod took too long to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some adjustments to the script that made the operation work:

```
with DAG('test_kube', default_args=default_args, description='Kubernetes Operator',
         schedule_interval='00 12 01 * *') as dag:
    k = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='kubenm',
                              image="gcr.io/project/teste-kube:latest", #Image path was incorrect 
                              name="test",
                              in_cluster=True, #To trigger cluster kubeconfig.
                              image_pull_policy="Always",  #In my case, I need the image update to occur whenever there is an update
                              task_id="test",
                              is_delete_operator_pod=False,
                              hostnetwork=False,
                              dag=dag
                              )

    k
```

Comment: what were the changes to fix the too long exception? in_cluster=True did fix the first problem but I am in the same state and getting `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Pod Launching failed: Pod took too long to start` exception

Comment: @Am1rr3zA Do you tried to use the function inside KubernetesPodOperator: startup_timeout_seconds=120 (default). Maybe if you increase it it will work.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator